# Swift : Pass TableViewCell text to new ViewController's cell

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableview

How to pass the same text from tableVC  to the detail tableVC using an array populated in tableVC.

It is working in tableVC but no data passed into the detailVC.

They share one tableviewcell.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {  
  @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
}
```

tableVC

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var thecourseName = [String]()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 thecourseName = ["course 1 ","course 2 ","course 3 "]
 theimg = [UIImage(named: "109.png")!,UIImage(named: "110.png")!]

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

 // Configure the cell...

 cell.title.text = thecourseName[indexPath.row]
 return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ( segue == "toInfo") {
        var text = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var detailsVC: DetalisTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalisTableViewController
    detailsVC.courseName = thecourseName

    }  
}
```

detailVC

```
import UIKit

class DetalisTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   var courseName = [String]()

@IBOutlet var passedCourse: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.title.text = courseName[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

StoryBoard 
http://s18.postimg.org/mwkw5hf1l/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not passing any information to your detailViewController about the contents of the selected cell. Do this instead:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if ( segue.identifier == "toInfo") {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            var detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalisTableViewController
            println(thecourseName[indexPath.row])
            println(indexPath.row)
            detailsVC.courseName = thecourseName[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of passing the whole array of course names to `DetailsTableViewController`, your variable `courseName` just contains one:

```
var courseName: String = ""

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
     cell.title.text = courseName
     return cell
}
```

Comment: cell.title.text = courseName   > error exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0) error

Comment: That's intersting. You better make sure you've linked up your IBOutlet correctly. Try running again with `println(cell.title)` above `cell.title.text...`

Comment: I corrected after uploading the file and still not working : IBOutlet title connected to two label

Comment: Sorry. I missed this, but you need to check the segue's identifier variable. Use the above code I posted instead.

Comment: cell.title.text = courseName[indexPath.row]  >> it give an error :: cannot assign a value of type 'character’ to a value of type ‘String?'                 thank you bro for the great answer